# How to create cross domain test in Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, selenium, functional-testing

I need to make a test that opens one site and than opens another that are not from the same domain. How to do it in Selenium IDE? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Selenium IDE is not the best tool for this. Have a look at using Selenium WebDriver as that is not running in the JavaScript sandbox and allows more freedom to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method

Give base url as http://www.google.com

Give the following commands

```
open                      /
waitForPageToLoad      30000
open                http://mail.yahoo.com
waitForPageToLoad      30000
```

It will work